# Python 2.7.9 Installation

Tags: windows, python-2.7, installation

I have installed Python a million times, but this time I have been defeated.

System: Windows 7 Enterprise
64 Bit

No Anti-virus software

The problem:
I can start and use python from the command line however the shell fails to boot every time and gives me the following error:

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1BJB.jpg

I have showed the PATH so that you can see it's on the path. No other version of python is installed. I have tried restarted rebooting shutting down. Installing from ninite. ect ect ect ect

I have NO ANTIVIRUS I literally uninstalled everything else. I also have ran this, and given admin privileges to every file in that folder.

I have no idea what to do. Please give any possible advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The firewall rules on the server were blocking the application from running. I fixed this by using Linux, or simply called python from the command line in windows and used a different editor (Notepad++ with python extension)

Answer (score 0):

Try to diable firewall. Python connect IDLE throw socket, apparently firewall block it